# How to reference JQuery plugin for using autocomplete method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I want to use autocomplete method supported by JQuery UI.
but I'm facing an error "JavaScript runtime error: Object does not support 'autocomplete' property or method."
I've followed some post' suggestion for solving this error.
but I couldn't solve this.
if Somebody helps me, Thank u!

I downloaded jquery-ui-1.11.4, copied this in my project.
and referenced this in BundleConfig.vb and _Layout.vbhtml

**BundleConfig.vb**

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/Script/autocomplete").Include(
                "~/Script/jquery-ui.js",
                "~/Script/jquery-ui.min.js"
                ))

bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/autocomplete").Include(
                "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                "~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css"
                ))
```

**_Layout.vbhtml**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Script/autocomplete")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/autocomplete")
```

> **UPDATE_BundleConfig.vb**

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Class BundleConfig

  Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.timezones.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/Script/autocomplete").Include(
                "~/Script/jquery-ui.js",
                "~/Script/jquery-ui.min.js"
                ))

    bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"))

    bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/css").Include(
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
                "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css"))

    bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/autocomplete").Include(
                "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                "~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css"
                ))

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
    bundles.IgnoreList.Clear()

  End Sub

End Class
```

> **UPDATE_Layout.vbhtml(~/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Welcome to OkAccount</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")        
    @Scripts.Render("~/Script/autocomplete")

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/autocomplete")     

</head>

<body>

     @RenderBody()

</body>
```

Comment: Do not include both the unminified and minified versions (delete the `.min` files). Have you included `jquery-{version}.js` in your view? And show how you are using the plugin.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I've included `jquery-{version}.js`, I'm using the plugin just like this. `$(function () { $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) { } })`

Comment: Is jquery loaded before jquery-ui?

Comment: @Stephen yes, I've just updated my post. This is entire BundleConfig.vb.

Comment: You already have `ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui")` - why are you including it again? And you need to show how you have added the bundles in the view/layout (your code does not show `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I re-updated.: ), I couldn't catch ur meaning, Sorry. I re-render `ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui")` because I thought I can't use autocomplete method by using JQuery UI that I've originally referenced.

Comment: All you need is `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` (after `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and delete `@Scripts.Render("~/Script/autocomplete")`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke. just after deleting and adding them u mentioned, It works well :) Thank u!!

Comment: You also need to remove `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` - Ensure you only ever have one copy of each script (and use bundles in preference to using `<script>` tags)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Okay, Thank u for letting me know preference in this field. I'll keep your advice in mind.